# Assigning function argument to column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to add the input of a function to the column name created in the function.

```
new_col = function(dat_, period_) {
dat_ %>% mutate(paste0('mpg',period_) = mpg + period_
}

mtcars %>% newcol(20)
```

In this function, mpg20 should be created where it's values are equal to mpg + 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

new_col = function(dat_, period_) {
  dat_ %>% mutate(!!paste0('mpg',period_) := mpg + period_)
}

mtcars %>% new_col(20)

#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg20
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  41.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  41.0
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  42.8
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  41.4
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  38.7
#Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  38.1
#...
#...
```

`!!` and `:=` combination is used when we have a character variable at the LHS.

Comment: Would you please explain `!!` and `:=` in your code. Thanks.

Comment: @TarJae I added some explanation.